How to use phone number instead of email for registration and login in a C# ASP.NET Core 8 Web API with Identity User?
I have an ASP.NET Core 8.0 Web API application in C# using Identity User for registration and login. However, I want to use a phone number instead of an email address for these processes. I've tried several approaches, but none of them have worked so far.
Could anyone help me achieve this? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

You say you've tried several approaches, please show us one or more of these so we have a better idea what you're doing. But first off: you're not trying to use a numeric type for the phone number, are you?

You can create a custom user class that inherits from IdentityUser and override the properties you don't need, such as Email.
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace WebApplication17.Authentication
{
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        // Override the mailbox property here to make it optional
        public override string? Email { get; set; } = null;
        public override bool EmailConfirmed { get; set; } = false;
    }
}

Add Identity related configuration.
builder.Services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
{
    // Allow mobile phone numbers as usernames
    options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = false;
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedPhoneNumber = true;

    // Password Rules
    //...
});

Migration
Add-Migration AddCustomFieldsToApplicationUser
Update-Database


thanks for your help but how can i add the PhoneNumber property?
